# Keep activity alive when using register activity for result even if Dont keep activity is enabled

Tags: android

Is there a way to stop ActivityA from being terminated when it launches ActivityB using `registerForActivityResult` in Android, even when the "Don't keep activities" option is turned on? Are there any tricks or methods to keep ActivityA alive when switching to ActivityB in this scenario? I know we can use `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to recover data, but I'm curious if there's a way to ensure ActivityA stays running.

Comment: The whole reason that `registerForActivityResult` is written that way is because process death and recreation is unavoidable.